# CSS 3-D Transforms

Tags: javascript, css

I have a carousel that is working great using (previous) and (next) buttons. The problem I am having is the fact that when it spins, it doesn't stay in one place. So you can click through the carousel using the previous and next buttons, but the carousel is shifting from left to right and back. How do you make the carousel spin in place? I am assuming it has something to do with the x-axis? What part of the code (CSS or JavaScript) makes the carousel spin in place?

```
<style media="screen">

.containercaro {
  width: 210px;
  height: 140px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto 40px;
  -webkit-perspective: 1100px;
     -moz-perspective: 1100px;
       -o-perspective: 1100px;
          perspective: 1100px;
}

#carousel {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ( -182px );
     -moz-transform: translateZ( -182px );
       -o-transform: translateZ( -182px );
          transform: translateZ( -182px );
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
     -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
       -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
          transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
     -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1s;
       -o-transition: -o-transform 1s;
          transition: transform 1s;
}

#carousel figure {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 186px;
  height: 116px;
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  line-height: 116px;
  font-size: 80px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

#carousel figure:nth-child(1) { background: hsla(   0, 100%, 50%, 0.8 ); }
#carousel figure:nth-child(2) { background: hsla(  60, 100%, 50%, 0.8 ); }
#carousel figure:nth-child(3) { background: hsla( 120, 100%, 50%, 0.8 ); }
#carousel figure:nth-child(4) { background: hsla( 180, 100%, 50%, 0.8 ); }
#carousel figure:nth-child(5) { background: hsla( 240, 100%, 50%, 0.8 ); }
#carousel figure:nth-child(6) { background: hsla( 300, 100%, 50%, 0.8 ); }


#carousel figure:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(   0deg ) translateZ( 182px );
     -moz-transform: rotateY(   0deg ) translateZ( 182px );
       -o-transform: rotateY(   0deg ) translateZ( 182px );
          transform: rotateY(   0deg ) translateZ( 182px );
}
#carousel figure:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(  60deg ) translateZ( 182px );
     -moz-transform: rotateY(  60deg ) translateZ( 182px );
       -o-transform: rotateY(  60deg ) translateZ( 182px );
          transform: rotateY(  60deg ) translateZ( 182px );
}
#carousel figure:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(  120deg ) translateZ( 182px );
     -moz-transform: rotateY(  120deg ) translateZ( 182px );
       -o-transform: rotateY(  120deg ) translateZ( 182px );
          transform: rotateY(  120deg ) translateZ( 182px );
}
#carousel figure:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg ) translateZ( 182px );
     -moz-transform: rotateY( 180deg ) translateZ( 182px );
       -o-transform: rotateY( 180deg ) translateZ( 182px );
          transform: rotateY( 180deg ) translateZ( 182px );
}
#carousel figure:nth-child(5) {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY( 240deg ) translateZ( 182px );
     -moz-transform: rotateY( 240deg ) translateZ( 182px );
       -o-transform: rotateY( 240deg ) translateZ( 182px );
          transform: rotateY( 240deg ) translateZ( 182px );
}
#carousel figure:nth-child(6) {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY( 300deg ) translateZ( 182px );
     -moz-transform: rotateY( 300deg ) translateZ( 182px );
       -o-transform: rotateY( 300deg ) translateZ( 182px );
          transform: rotateY( 300deg ) translateZ( 182px );
}
```

Comment: Post your code. Clairvoyants are pretty rare these days.

Comment: @falguni http://www.w3fools.com/ !

Comment: updated with script above

Comment: I figured it out. In my .containercaro script, I needed to set the width to a wider girth so there isn't as much movement.

Comment: glad we could help;) You should either choose to delete your question or post an answer for yourself.